# iOS iPhone app not displaying correctly on some devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

So I've been working on a PDF reader for iOS, the app itself works fine on iPhone 6 and I think 5 as well, however on iPhone 4S and when running in compatibility mode on iPad it only displays this:

[iOS app on iPad /iPhone 4S](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAEjv.png)

I cannot submit my app to the iTunes store without fixing this issue, does anybody know what is causing it?

The app is coded in Objective C

Comment: Check for devices support for your app in `xcodeProject--> General`

Comment: Looks like your auto-layout constraints don't support the smaller resolutions.  Check the debugger, or use a tool such as Reveal to find out what is going on.

Comment: cheers, I will look into it.